# What do Americans mean by Coffee and Cream?

Tags: coffee, dairy

When Americans say "Would you like cream in your coffee?", do they mean *powdered creamer* (milk or milk-substitute)? Basically what South Africans know as [Cremora](https://www.cremora.co.za) or do they put heavy or double cream in their coffee? Is cream some sort of collective noun for any type of dairy that is put into coffee?

Comment: There's also light cream (≈UK single cream) which is more likely, and half-and-half (50% light cream, 50% whole milk), which I believe to be the answer. Being neither American nor a fan of dairy in my coffee, I'll leave it to the experts to provide something definitive. I have a suspicion that "cream" could occasionally turn out to be milk, but maybe only when cultures clash. Cream***er*** on the other hand is a substitute for the real thing, and a poor one unless you can't have dairy.  See [US Dairy - types of cream](https://www.usdairy.com/news-articles/types-of-cream)

Comment: @ChrisH "Cream" pretty much never means milk in the US because we would just say "milk". If you're at most restaurants and you ask for "cream" you're more likely to get half and half than anything else, in my experience. I've never seen anyone get milk when asking for cream.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I suppose I was imagining someone asking for cream as a guest in  a home/workplace  and getting milk because there was no cream, half&half, etc.  But then in my house you'd be lucky to even get cow's milk.

Comment: Even worse: the powdered "non-dairy creamer" (awful stuff, but common in many places because it doesn't require refrigeration) is often not actually non-dairy - Kosher certification will show a "D" for dairy, but it satisfies a crazy legal definition of non-dairy - see [this example from Amazon](https://amzn.to/4bhVQwj).

Comment: @ChrisH I would consider it impolite on the part of the host to not clarify what dairy is available and I doubt I'm alone. As in: "Do want anything for your coffee?"; "Just cream please"; "I'm out of half and half but I have whipping cream and whole milk"; "Oh just sugar then, thanks."

Comment: @ToddWilcox fair enough - though in your example you could make some

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I think it's because it's lactose-free that they can get away with it.  Big international brands just don't care.  Similarly Maggi (Nestlé) coconut milk powder has the same cow's milk derivative in it ([sodium caseinate](https://www.maggi.co.uk/products/maggi-coconut-milk-powder-mix-300g/) - the labelling on their website is clearer than the pack I bought a while ago).  It's probably the same dairy derivative in all non-non-dairy creamers.

Comment: In France, when asking for "un café-crème" in a café, you get a coffee with milk, at least in Paris; and that's more common than asking for "un café au lait" (coffee with milk). I remember my mother complaining, back in the 70's, that nearly no more cafés were offering true cream. I guess this was also a matter of hygiene: previously they would give you a little cream pot that would thereafter be used on other tables.

Comment: By "cream" they mean "creamer" -- a synthetic white liquid that has a very long shelf life and can produce unknown health problems. None of its ingredients has never been close to a cow or other animal, and it's problably made of discarded waste from nuclear power plants. Stay away from it. Sorry for the irony, but can't stress more that should not eat this.

Comment: American in English cafe: "Could I have a coffee without cream, please?" Waitress: "I'm sorry. We have no cream. I could give it to you without milk?"

Comment: Um, actually, it is already somewhat strange what Americans usually refer to as "coffee".

Comment: @Transistor Developing this slightly, in Soviet Russia one could visit a cafe and ask for coffee without cream, only to be told that the only thing available was coffee without milk. For coffee without cream they would be directed to the cafe across the street.  That the two are different requires a Hegelian argument (I'm reusing a joke by Slavoj Zizek here).

Comment: Cultural reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_t15vNuXP0

Comment: It depends on where you go.  If you're at a "coffee shop" that is at least as fancy as a starbucks, you'll almost certainly recieve half-and-half if you ask for "cream".  Some places may take the term generically and ask you to be specific about half-and-half vs milk vs plant-based alternatives.  Fast food joints and gas stations may or may not have half-and-half and instead have "creamer", and if you ask for "cream" and "creamer" is all they have they'll likely just give it to you and not attempt to clarify.  "creamer" is always the fake stuff whatever it is.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's no consistent answer to this, as you can see from the comments below there's it's slightly contentious.

Usually cream when offered with coffee refers to either half and half (half milk and half light cream, about 12% fat) or a non-dairy liquid creamer like Coffee Mate. The half and half could be fresh, or in little single-serve containers in which case it's probably UHT so it doesn't require refrigeration. Non-dairy creamer is almost always in single-serve containers.

Less likely it could also mean light cream or very rarely heavy cream. If it's powder people will usually say it's creamer.

Comment: I would say that actual "light cream/single cream" cream would be unusual... half-and-half is about as high a fat level as I've seen.

Comment: It's true @Sneftel, I know a few people who like light cream in their coffee, personally I think even half and half is too much.

Comment: This is generally right, but I'd emphasize that (in the US) "cream" means "half & half" or "fluid non-dairy creamer" the vast preponderance of times by putting that first.  Then allow for the possibility of other options (milk, light cream etc.).

Comment: @Dave, I have lived in the U.S. all my life, and I have decades of coffee drinking behind me. "Cream" *never* means "fluid non-dairy creamer" to me.  But half & half, yes, that's absolutely what I would expect in the context of coffee.  I do take cream (i.e. half & half) in my coffee, and I will accept non-dairy creamer as a substitute if necessary, but I do not call any form of the latter "cream".

Comment: @JohnBollinger if there's a little bowl of plastic creamer containers on the restaurant table, they'd be referred to as "cream" even if they're non-dairy creamer.  Or at least that is my experience.

Comment: John: it may not mean it to you, but it does to lots of other folks, particularly in the NE.  I was just on a trip to Boston, asked for cream for my coffee at the hotel, and was handed some Coffee-Mate.

Comment: @Dave, I don't doubt that there is variation in usage, not only regionally but among individuals. That's what the question is about, after all, and it's in fact my point.  Your claim is too strong.  I do not contest that some in the U.S. will understand "cream" exactly as you describe.  But it's not correct to generalize that to the whole population, nor to such a large majority that it is reasonable to ignore the minority (not to stipulate, however, that the others *are* a minority).

Comment: I can chime in to support the "significant variation in usage" position, as someone who will readily interpret "cream" as broadly as "anything you put in coffee that makes it light".

Comment: "most likely it's half & half or some sort of non-dairy creamer liquid." Yes, but it depends on the context. At a coffee shop and most restaurants, it will be half & half. In a hotel lobby, out-of-the way gas station, or office cafeteria, it will be non-dairy creamer (powdered or liquid) more often than not.

Comment: this answer could be improved by defining half & half, because this product isn't available in lots of places (e.g. it's basically unheard of in the UK, except in US media, where we get little idea of what it actually is beyond it being some sort of dairy product; I suspect a lot of people would incorrectly assume it's similar to our semi-skimmed milk)

Comment: There's some good comments here, I've done my best to capture them in an edit.

Comment: “Non-dairy creamer is almost always in single-serve containers.” True in restaurants, but the question doesn’t specify that. If you’re over at someone’s home, they almost-certainly do not have single-serve containers, and are going to pour whatever they mean by “cream” from a larger container (IME, usually in the cup to quart range).

Comment: At this point, as a long- time resident of mid-size cities in the US, we might note it's getting even more complicated as the number of choices proliferates.  The word "cream" is increasingly a placeholder for Some-Dairy-Like-Thing as people increasingly use more than a few different soy or nut "milks" alongside a choice of cow milk derivatives - maybe a dozen options some places.  In my daily life in coffee shops, servers ask "Do you want room?" and I'm old enough to understand "room for cream" but perhaps people 20 years younger don't think "cream" at all.

Comment: I did see a woman try to cream her coffee with nonfat milk. Maybe she thinks cream means something else.

Answer (score 17):

#### tl;dr: "cream," means heavy cream or half-and-half.

For context, I live in the US.

If you visit my house and ask for cream in your coffee, I will give you heavy cream. I suppose it is *possible* to find light cream in the US but this is so exceedingly rare in a normal supermarket that we'd normally say it doesn't exist.

Half-and-half (approximately 1:1 cream and milk) is very common and it used in many restaurants to replace cream. It is common largely because it gives much the same feeling in one's coffee as cream but is significantly better on the health. If I had this, I would give it to you and consider it equivalent to cream.

If I didn't have cream but I had milk, I would tell you that. Most likely, I would offer by milkfat percentage I have available: whole, 2%, 1% or skim.

If I didn't have milk, I would tell you what else I have that may substitute. Lactose-free milk is increasingly common and even more so non-cow milks such as almond, oat, coconut, etc. (Soy milk, on the other hand, has nearly disappeared from American supermarkets due to an irrational fear of soy products.)

I would not offer you creamer, mostly because I drink my own coffee black and I don't ordinarily have fresh creamer on hand. Much of the creamer available in this country is sweetened and artificially flavored, French vanilla and hazelnut being very common. I have met social groups where putting this sort of creamer in your coffee is *de rigueur* but I cannot recall anyone who has ever called this, "cream."

In some (American) circles, "creamer," is of the dry-powder variety, which can vary from the dry version of fresh creamer to simply powdered milk of some variety. It is sometimes sweetened and often not made of any ingredient that began its life as cow milk. In any case, if all I had was powdered creamer, I may offer it to you but only with significant disclaimers.

I do not frequent Starbucks or any other coffee shop. Perhaps someone who does, or someone who works at one, can shed some light as to their corporate standards for this. There are may Americans who consider what Starbucks does to be both the original and definitive way of serving coffee.

Comment: "I suppose it is possible to find light cream in the US but this is so exceedingly rare in a normal supermarket that we'd normally say it doesn't exist." - I don't know who "we" are, but in my region of the US light cream is very easy to find beside the regular cream in normal supermarket, and in about equal quantities.

Comment: @LaconicDroid really?  What part of the US do you live in?  Apparently this is a regional thing.  Here on the West Coast, one only finds light cream in restaurant supply stores, never in the grocery store.

Comment: I've seen it in grocery stores in the East Coast (MD), Midwest (MI) and Mountain West (CO). So maybe it's just not easily available on the West Coast?

Comment: In any Starbucks I have ever been to, if you say "cream" you will get half and half. They do usually have many other things available (different fat levels of milk, plus many non-dairy milk alternatives), but if you wanted one of those you would have to specify that.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was raised in NYC, never saw it in a store there except for specialty stores. I lived in Denver, don't remember ever seeing it at King Sooper. I live in Texas now, I've never seen it at HEB, although you can get pretty much anything at Whole Foods or Central Market (both also locally based). Not saying it's impossible to find, just that it's not a normal thing.

Comment: By "fresh creamer", do you mean liquid as opposed to powdered?  AFAIK both types are made from sodium caseinate, hydrogenated vegetable oils and other yummies.

Comment: @StephanSamuel My local King Soopers in Denver carries it regularly. Maybe it's not as commonplace as, say, half&half or whipping cream, but it's definitely not impossible to find.

Comment: Downvoted, because when coffee with cream [and sugar], is ordered, 100% of the time, the consumer expects half-and-half.  Never is heavy cream, light cream, or whipping cream expected.  Or any variation of milk, for that matter.

Comment: On a tangent, soy milk seems to have pretty much been replaced by oat milk here in northern Europe as well, even though I'm not aware of any significant "fear of soy products" on this side of the pond, irrational or otherwise. IME soy milk tends to taste pretty nasty in coffee, though. (To be fair, so did early oat milks, too. I believe Oatly was the first brand around here to come up with a high-fat "barista" oat milk that actually tastes good in coffee, although plenty of other brands seem to have since copied their recipe.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I think there's a fairly wide variety of what people like in their coffee, but I'd have to agree with you that most of the non-cow milk is pretty icky, especially as you say, with low fat content. I'm told however that traditional Italian cappuccino _etc._ is made with non-fat cow milk, which seems enigmatic to me if it's true.

Comment: *"[Half-and-half] is common largely because it gives much the same feeling in one's coffee as cream but is significantly better on the health."* Assuming facts not in evidence, your honor - both the health claim (fat isn't necessarily bad for health) and the causality (it's much more likely to be a financial decision, or it could even be a matter of taste: they believe that people like half-and-half in their coffee more than they like actual cream).

Answer (score 14):

Based on my experiences as a coffee drinker who has lived in 5 US states and drunk coffee in at least 14 others, here's the things they could be offering you in order of probability/common use:

1. [Half-and-half](https://www.allrecipes.com/article/what-is-half-and-half/)
2. Full-fat milk
3. Liquid non-dairy creamer
4. Dairy heavy cream
5. Some form of non-dairy milk (such as oat milk or soy milk)

While liquid non-dairy creamer is [the most commonly used](https://www.statista.com/statistics/281805/us-households-usage-of-non-dairy-cream-substitutes-trend/) of the above, most of the time Americans distinguish between it and "real cream"; they would be more likely to say "creamer" or a brand name than calling it "cream".  However, some people and some regions make less of a distinction. Also, creamer is more likely to be called "cream" if no other options are available, such as in many workplaces.

At the same time, non-dairy milks might be offered, but outside of certain venues (e.g. vegan restaurants) the host is most likely to distinguish them from "regular cream".

There's a couple of cultural reasons why Americans are usually careful to distinguish between dairy and non-dairy options. One is that we have a strong national dairy industry and there's some dairy pride.  The second is that a lot of Americans have lactose intolerance, so hosts want to make sure they know that non-dairy options are available.

Comment: Notably the probability/order shifts depending on where you are. A fancy coffee shop probably offers a lot of nondairy milks, so they're likely to be more precise/literal. A big chain probably has a single default. A diner is more likely to use non-dairy creamer (and to provide it individually packaged).

Comment: @Cascabel yeah, and the diner would have the creamer (or sometimes shelf-stable cream servings) available on the counter without asking.

Answer (score 3):

Cream for coffee means "table cream" or "light cream" like this:

https://www.safeway.com/shop/product-details.960422635.html?productId=960422635

But it is common to say "cream" for half-and-half or artificial creamer, unfortunately.

By [US law](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-21/chapter-I/subchapter-B/part-131), "cream" is defined as:

> Cream  means the liquid milk product high in fat separated from milk, which may have been adjusted by adding thereto: Milk, concentrated milk, dry whole milk, skim milk, concentrated skim milk, or nonfat dry milk. Cream contains **not less than 18 percent milkfat**.

while "half and half" is defined as:

> Half-and-half is the food consisting of a **mixture of milk and cream** which contains not less than 10.5 percent but less than 18 percent milkfat. It is pasteurized or ultra-pasteurized, and may be homogenized.

Comment: Can you post a synopsis of the link?

Comment: I've never heard of that product before.  I would accept it as "cream", but that's certainly not what I'm thinking of when I say the word.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Canada is more clear about it.  Cream that is 18% milk fat is the standard cream for coffee. https://www.obviouslygoodmilk.ca/en/products/creams/lucerne-18-coffee-cream If I was at an upscale restaurant that's what I would expect them to give me if I asked for cream for my coffee.

Comment: Well me, too, more or less, though that 18% MF cream would more typically be called "half & half" everywhere that I have lived in the U.S..

Comment: @JohnBollinger I use half-and-half at home, but it is usually lower fat, 10% milk fat is specified in Canada: https://www.sealtest.ca/en/products/creams/half-and-half-cream-10

Comment: In the U.S. the FDA defines half & half as having between 10.5% and 18% MF.  The next step up from that is "[light] whipping cream", which has at least 30% MF.

Comment: @JohnBollinger and "cream" is required to be higher than "half and half" "Cream contains not less than 18 percent milkfat" https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-21/chapter-I/subchapter-B/part-131

Comment: Fair enough, @DavePhD.  Except in my experience, light cream is not a product commonly seen in U.S. stores, nor, therefore, served in U.S. homes.  I imagine that this is related to why many folks in the U.S. think of half & half as "cream".

Comment: Since every answer here needs a dozen comments: "coffee cream" (18%) in Canada is a relatively new thing in grocery stores (like in the past 10-15 years) and most restaurants use "half and half" (10% here) for coffee. Started seeing "table cream" (6%) around the same time, though it's not as popular. "Whipping cream" is 33-36% fat depending where you are in the country.

Comment: The Safeway link appears to be blocked outside the US. Could you provide a screenshot?